# How to create forms using Tables in C#?

Tags: c#

I'm using C# .NET 4.0 VS 2010. Newbie.

In the old versions of VB (not .net), there is what you call Form Wizard that creates Forms with automatic Labels and Textboxes just by declaring the table. (with Grids if more than one tables with 1:many relationship)

I tried searching the internet but all i got was either how to create a wizard form (not what i want) or create database from form. I'm also not fully familiar yet with IDE of VS.

Did VS rename it? Removed it? Can somebody point me where in VS i can do this?

Comment: You may want to investigate the Lightswitch version of Visual Studio: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/ff796201.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the comments in this thread: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/524951/data-form-wizard-is-missing-in-visual-studio-2008, this designer Template ("Data Form" no longer exists in Visual Studio. AFAIK, you'll have to do this by hand.